# finding right selector for pagination with scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors, web-crawler

I'm trying to extract data from this forum:

https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all

I get the data from the first page. I use the css selector `'li.selected > a::attr(href)'` Unfortunately I can not get all other data from other pages.

What is the right path for xpath or css selectors for pagination?

Python:

```
import scrapy

class ForumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pregnancy"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        for thread in response.css('div.af-thread-item'):
            yield{
                'threadTitle': thread.css('span.thread-title::text').extract_first(),
                'username': thread.css('div.user-name::text').extract_first()
            }
        next_page = response.css('li.selected > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page))
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="af-pagination " role="navigation"><ul><li class="selected">
<a href="https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all">1</a></li><li>
<a href="https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all/p2">2</a></li><li>
<a href="https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all/p3">3</a></li><li>
<a href="https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all/p4">4</a></li><li>
<a href="https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all/p5">5</a></li><li>
<a href="https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all/p6">6</a></li><li>
<a href="https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all/p7">7</a></li><li>
<a href="https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all/p8">8</a></li><li>
...
```

link of next page:
https://schwangerschaft.gofeminin.de/forum/all/p2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `response.css('link[rel=next]::attr(href)').get()`, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Given the way the way this particular websites navbar is built, what I like to do in these situations is use xpath. Given that the current page will have a class of "selected", I would select the "selected" class and then use "following-sibling" syntax with the index of 1 to obtain the very following tags.

In your case:

```
response.xpath("//li[@class='selected']/following-sibling::li[1]/a/@href").extract_first()
```

So no matter which page you are in, you are dynamically choosing the "next" page.

Comment: vezunchik answer does the same thing and is even shorter. the reason I use this method is that I've run into situations where there is no "next" tag in pagination/navbar.